# Calling Page Methods of UserControl/Page using MSAJax

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to call usercontrol methods/events using MSAJAX. I wanted to update my usercontrol by calling one of its events when a property from its parent page changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

PageMethods are static thus have no access to instance members such as UserControls.

You might try using an update panel but as written it seems you may have a crisis of design.

Good luck.